# Webmatrix - Populating Select Box from previous Selection Box Value

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, webmatrix

Hello Currently using webmatrix and wish to use select boxes to drill down the user type so they can get to the right input form.

I want to know the best way to do this using jquery in webmatrix for example:

Select Box 1 --> Biz type: accommodation, store, service, wholesaler etc if select store then select box 2 gets populated with:

Select Box 2 --> food store, electrical store, pet store, clothing store etc
and so forth

then submit button that goes to form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Mike Brind's article should answer your question: [WebMatrix - jQuery Cascading Dropdown Lists](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/196/WebMatrix-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists)